# I didnt get my pacman to reach to its destination.. nd having an error mentioned below

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
[SearchAgent] using function depthFirstSearch
[SearchAgent] using problem type PositionSearchProblem
Path found with total cost of 999999 in 0.0 seconds
Search nodes expanded: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\vpn\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\Project 1 - Search\pacman.py", line 672, in <module>
    runGames( **args )
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\vpn\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\Project 1 - Search\pacman.py", line 638, in runGames
    game.run()
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\vpn\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\Project 1 - Search\game.py", line 662, in run
    action = agent.getAction(observation)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\vpn\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\Project 1 - Search\searchAgents.py", line 121, in getAction
    if i < len(self.actions):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

m working on a project in which i have to test my pacman agent to reach to its destination in less possible space and time complexity by applying DFS(Depth First Algorithm)

My code for it is

```
stack = util.Stack()
    explored = list()
    start = problem.getStartState()

    for item in problem.getSuccessors(start):
        state = item[0]
        path = list()
        path.append(item[1])
        stateInfo = (state, path)
        stack.push(stateInfo)
    explored.append(start)

    while stack.isEmpty():
        state = stack.pop()

        if problem.isGoalState(state[0]):
            return state[1]

        for states in problem.getSuccessor(state[0]):
            newstate = states[0]
            newpath = list(state[1])
            newpath.append(states[1])
            newstateInfo = (newstate, newpath)
            stack.push(newstateInfo)
        explored.append(state[0])
```

What should i suppose to do now.. my pacman agent get stuck to its starting position in east dirction opposite to its destination.
The supporting files to run the agent is mentioned in https://www.edx.org/courses/BerkeleyX/CS188.1x/2012_Fall/courseware/Week_2/Project_1_Search/

Comment: Your error is `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`. Post the code that contains `getAction if i < len(self.actions)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what is going on (though I can't be certain given the limited amount of code  in the question).

My guess is that the code you've posted is getting called to set up the variable `self.actions` where you're getting an error. The error is happening because you're getting `None` returned from the function, rather than the list you expect.

The underlying bug is that your main loop has it's test backwards. You want `while not stack.isEmpty()`, rather than what you have. Because you've just pushed several values onto the stack, the loop as written exits immediately. After the loop you reach the end of the function, which is equivalent to returning `None` in Python. That None is causing the exception later.

Even if you fix the broken loop, falling off the end of the function can happen anyway if a path cannot be found to the goal state. I suggest adding code to detect this, and respond appropriately. You could raise an exception (since it shouldn't happen in normal situations), or maybe return an empty list.

There's another issue where you're not checking if a newly visited state has already been explored. This could lead to an infinite loop, as you search from one state to a neighbor and then back. A `set` will also be better than a `list` for `explored`. You can check it with `if state in explored` (which also works on lists, but less efficiently).

As a side issue, some of your variables are very poorly named. `state` different types at different times, and having a second variable `states` makes it even more confusing, especially with indexing thrown in.

I suggest unpacking the tuples you pushed onto the stack with the code `state, path = stack.pop()`, which will solve part of the issue. Then just rename `states` to something else (or perhaps unpack it too, with something like `for neighbor, direction in problem.getSuccessor(state)`) and you'll be good to go.

You can also save a few lines of code by pushing the start state to your stack, rather than doing an extra loop over its neighbors in the setup code.